# Template partial specialization with multiple template argument in cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

x.h

```
class X
{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    struct Bar
    {
    public:
        template<typename T1> void bar(T2 const& t2);
    };
}
```

x.cpp

How do I define the function?

Comment: I think it would help if you could explain what the goal is. The way it's written, I don't understand the intention. But as a general remark, definitions of template functions are usually found in the header, not in the .cpp file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem, `T1` overshadows the `T1` in `struct Bar`. You could change it to `T3` like the following:

```
class X
{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    struct Bar
    {
    public:
        template<typename T3> void bar(T3 const& t3); // Could define it here {}
    };
}; // <-- Missing closing brace

template <typename T1, typename T2>
template <typename T3>
void X::Bar<T1, T2>::bar(T3 const& t3){} // Assuming `T3 const& t3` otherwise...
```

Or

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
template <typename T3>
void X::Bar<T1, T2>::bar(T2 const& t2){}
```

Then call it like so:

```
X::Bar<int, int> b;
b.bar(1);
```

or

```
X::Bar<int, int> b;
b.bar<int>(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
class X
{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    struct Bar
    {
    public:
        void bar(T2 const& t2);
    };
};


template <typename T1, typename T2> void X::Bar<T1, T2>::bar( T2 const & t2 )
{


}
```

Note that I removed the `template<typename T1>` off of `void bar` since that qualification is already part of `template<typename T1, typename T2> struct Bar`.

Edit: If you really need a third type to qualify `bar`, then consider this example:

```
class X
{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    struct Bar
    {
    public:
        template <typename T3>
        void bar(T1 const &t1, T2 const &t2, T3 const &t3);
    };
};


template <typename T1, typename T2>
template <typename T3>
void X::Bar<T1, T2>::bar( T1 const &t1, T2 const &t2, T3 const &t3 )
{


}
```

Comment: no template<typename T1> void bar(T2 const& t2);

Comment: That typename shadows the outer T1.  If they are the same type there is no need to re-declare.  If you really need three distinct types, see the edit I'm about to add.

Answer (score 1):

As with any template, you need to include the definition in any translation unit which might implicitly instantiate it, so you should put it in the header file rather than in the .cpp file. If you want to include the definition of the function out-of-line, here's how to write it:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> template<typename T3>
void X::Bar<T1, T2>::bar(T2 const &t2) {
  // ...
}
```

Also of note is that your class definition is ill-formed, because you shadow the outer template's parameter `T1` with the inner template's parameter `T1`. You need to rename one of them.